# Formula for Workdays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calendar

I am currently creating a calendar, i need to input a text designated to each day. "WD1" for every first working day of the month then at the last day of the month it must be "WD-1" until "WD-8", weekends must be excluded into this. WD1 and so on until it meets the WD-8.
I cannot create a dynamic formula for this to lessen the manual inputting of this, please help me. [image]

[image]

Comment: are you aware of the built-in formulas for this?

Comment: there is no built in formulas for this, i am doing it manually.

Comment: So you need to count workdays starting at the beginning of the month until there's only 8 left at which point you count down from 8 to 1, is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct, and also i need to have the output WD1 and so on.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the workday-related functions?  This should be able to be accomplished with an `IF` statement and the `NETWORKDAYS` function.  (By the way, I meant *function* earlier, not *formula*.  There are *no* built-in formulas.)

Comment: I tried this formula =IF(NETWORKDAYS(F4,G16),("WD1")) but this just for the workday1 i can't figure it out how to add for the other workdays especially the WD-1 to WD-8.

Comment: **Ignore the `WD-` for now**, that's just formatting (no more relevant to the formula right now than "what color to choose" is), it can be added last. The important part is the numbers.  On the same note, I see that you started with getting the formatting of the calendar itself just right.  There's lots of reasons to ignore that stuff until last (partly because you might end up having to do the formatting again)

Comment: To get the `WD-xx`, format teh cells with a custom number format of `\W\D-0`.

Comment: I'll write an answer showing an overview of how I would tackle this.  (Give me a few minutes)  ...of course keep in mind that, like many tasks in Excel, there are many different ways the same thing can be accomplished.  Just think now if there's any information you're missing in the explanation. For example, does anything change next month?  Are there holidays? Is it always "8 before the end" that's significant.  (And I'd like to know the importance of the last 8 - but that's purely out of curiosity)

Comment: The real question here is whether the **June 2018** cell is 6/1/18 formatted as mmmm yyyy or if it is a string you typed in.

Comment: @Jeeped - speaking of multiple ways to do things, I prefer `"WD-"0` but the result is the same.

Comment: @ashleedawg - I try to avoid quotes in answers since they only result in another question from someone trying to use them in VBA.

Comment: @Jeeped this is the formula for the JUNE 2018 ="June "&CalendarYear

Comment: oh-key-doh-key then. Put 6/1/18 into that merged cell and format it (Ctrl+1) as *mmmm yyyy*.

Comment: @ashleedawg every month that have a 31 the WD-1 will be moved. WD-1 will always at the last day of the month so if there is 31 it will be the WD-1 and if the last day is 30 it will be the WD-1.

Comment: It's easiest to just get it working first and we'll worry about where to get your start date and end date from afterwards.  I don't know if posting in pieces like this is more or less confusing, but you'll understand what I'm doing at the end.  :-)   ...which might imply this is more confusing... but that's what you get for free labour in my spare time and at the end you'll have a working solution.  :-)

Comment: ...almost there. If it's too confusing like this, just come back it a bit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do:

- Start with a **blank worksheet**. (Don't worry, you can copy your pretty formatting over after, but again, that should usually be the **last** step.
- **In cell `A1` enter `=DATE(2018,6,1)`**
- **In cell `B1` enter `=A1+1`**
- Select (highlight) cells `A1` to `B1` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to go to number formats.  Choose `Custom` from the left and then in the `Type` field enter: `ddd mmm d`.  Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

  You should have the dates of June 1st & 2nd, 2018.
  <sub>(I would normally just enter `2018-06-01` in `A1` but that's for **my** country; depending on what country you're in, you're date format may be different - and if entered incorrectly won't be recognized as a date.)</sub>
- Next, highlight cells `B1` to `AD1` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  You should now have dates for the whole month.

---

- Now click cell `A1` and in the **Name Box** to the left of the formula bar, type `FirstDay` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  This gives the cell a **Defined Name** of `FirstDay`, like an Alias (aka "named range")

  [image: img]
- Click cell `AD1` (which should be June 30) and give it a name of `LastDay'

---

- In cell `A2` enter formula: `=IF(NETWORKDAYS(A1,LastDay)>8,NETWORKDAYS(firstDay,A1),NETWORKDAYS(A1,LastDay))`
- Select (highlight) cells `A2` to `AD2` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to fill the formula to the right.

---

Now, June 30 should have a `0` below it.  The hard part is done.  The middle part should look something like this:  (you'll see why when we finish.)
[image: img]

---

- Select cells `A1` and `A2` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Choose `Custom` again from the left side and this time the `Type` is [`\W\D-0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033707/formula-for-workdays/50034585#comment87085010_50033707).  Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Select cell `A2` and **hold** <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to open the **Conditional Formatting** dialog. (Alternatively, you could click `Home` –> `Conditional Formatting` –> `New Rule`.)
- In **Conditional Formatting** dialog, click 'Use a Formula to determine which cells to format' dialogue box.  In the ***`Format values where this formula is true`*** box type: `=B2=A2` and then click the <kbd>Format</kbd> button.
- Under the `Font` tab click `Color` and choose **WHITE**.

  (We're making the cells with repeating numbers (weekends, etc) *still have a value* but be ***invisible***.)

  [image: img] <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> "three times" to close all the dialogs.

---

- Click cell `A2` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to **Copy** it.
- Select (highlight) cells `A2` to `AD2` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open the **Paste Values** dialog.
- Choose `Values` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

---

Basically all that's left is formatting.

- Highlight all the cell by clicking the top left corner and make the cells equal width (like the beginning of the animation below).  I always use "Wednesdays" for sizing since they're the widest. :-)
- Drag the cells into the positions you want, and then copy the *formatting only* from before or reformat now as you see fit.

[image: img]

---

## After Formatting:

Ten minutes of formatting as re-positioning as required, and we have something similar to what your example looks like:

<sub>Click images to enlarge.</sub>
[image: final]

<sub>Personally I like to throw in the sideways text to save vertical space, bu that's a matter of personal preference.</sub>
[image: alternate final]

> Maybe my delivery could've been a bit better so I'll post my `XLSM` Demo file here in a couple minutes for you to **download** if you like, and then clean up the post a bit...

---

### Download file [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=65823293201188325623)

Remember cell B2 should be set to the first day of the month, everything based off there.
Have fun!

Comment: i would like to ask why is the first day of the month is also negative(-) it must be WD1, how can i do it? the WD-1 will start at the last day of the month

Comment: oh hold on i didn't know that was a minus sign i figured it was a dash.  (So did @Jeeped when we were discussing it)

Comment: @aicirtap that will be easy enough to fix.  Also I'm adjusting the formula so it will change dynamically to the correct day of week to start.  You'll just enter the month the the big green month part as, for example, "2018-06-01" and it will format it properly.  Dates should hold a "complete" date whenever possible and only display what you want with formatting....  similarly, it would not have worked to include the "WD" as part of the value when it only needs to be "displayed" (hence why I didn't realize that was a negative.)  The cell isn't holding "negative one", it's one. But a quick fix

Comment: sorry i did not include it clearly at my question but yes it is a negative working day (-).

Comment: I'm also actually removing the "firstday" and "lastday" names and instead having the formulas look at "the minimum date in the first row" and "the maximum date in the last row".  But it's always the last **`8`** you want counted down right?  ie., even when February has 28 days?

Comment: yes @ashleedawg. For example of what i am talking about is June 29 is the last working day of the month so it will be the "WD-1" and "WD-8" will be June 20. Then "WD1" will be June 1 and so on until it meets the WD-8. So June 19 will be "WD13"

Comment: I fixed that, I will update the instructions tomorrow with the little adjustments I've made, for now I will get this working for multiple months and post it for you to download.  (Just for the record, as I said at the beginning, [so] is not normally a place to get a "free spreadsheet designer" but you happened to catch me in a mood -- I'm a bot of a geek for this kind of stuff.  Which reminds me of the other reason to save formatting until last: it's the most fun, so save the best for last after the work is done, lol...  Anyway, I'll just be a few more mins

Comment: (remember when I asked at the beginning if there's anything we need to consider that might change depending on the month, before starting)  *sigh* one thing neither of us thought of...  Since your weeks start on Mondays, and July 1st is a Sunday, July needs 6 rows, not 5...  I'm definitely not adding that right now.  Maybe you can just skip July 1 since it's a Sunday and start the calendar on the 2nd?

Comment: I thought it is clear in my sample photo, sorry. My example is not July it is June 2018. Thank you so much you are a great help to me.

Comment: yes it can skip the weekends since what i need in this calendar is the working days only.

Comment: Monday December 31 will be the same problem, it's a 6th week.  Which country are you in?  Is it standard that calendars start on Mondays like this? (I'm not changing it now anyhow, I'm just curious!)

Comment: I added your link.  I'm outta here, computers about to die. ask me any questions tomorrow

Comment: that would be fine @ashleedawg if you would not change it, this calendar will be use as a planner to know what are the tasks needs to be done monthly and they are familiar in looking at the Working days that's why it is important. I am from Philippines by the way.

Comment: @ashleedawg - please try to leave *something* for the neophyte to discover/learn/interpret for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [ashleedawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112776/ashleedawg); start with a blank worksheet.

1. In A1 put `6/1/18` then merge A1:G1 and format the cell as *mmmm yyyy*. Apply left alignment and anything else your heart desires.
2. In A4 put,

   ```
   =$A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1, 3)+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)+INT((ROW()-ROW($4:$4))/2)*7
   ```
3. Apply a conditional formatting rule to A4 that will grey non-month days based on the following formula,

   ```
   =text(a4, "mmyy")<>text($a$1, "mmyy")
   ```
4. In A2 put,

   ```
   =UPPER(TEXT(A3, "dddd"))
   ```

4, in A3 put,

```
    =IF(AND(TEXT(A4, "mmyy") = TEXT($A$1, "mmyy"), NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A4, A4, 1)), NETWORKDAYS.INTL($A$1, A4, 1), TEXT(,))
```

5. Apply a custom number format of `\W\D-0;;;` to A3.
6. Fill A2:A4 right to G2:G4.
7. Copy A3:G4 to A5, A7, A9 and A11.
8. Format to your heart's content.

That's all you should need. If you require some oddball WD-x countdown as the days approach the end of the month, it's just maths.

[image]

To truly see the versatility of this type of maths driven calendar, change the date in A1 to another month and/or year.

Comment: But how can i make the first working day of the month will not be negative (-), i need to make it WD1 and the last day of the month will be WD-1 to WD-8. In your example it is just continuous but what i need to do is to start the last day of the month with "WD-1".

Comment: I've shown you how to get the numbers you want. Everything else is comparison and subtraction. You might need to use the eomonth function with a1. It's just maths and I assume you can perform basic subtraction.

Comment: btw, I don't see a negative 'working day' in my example.